How to move open source to enterprise edition in magento 2.4.6
I want to upgrade magento magento/project-community-edition version 2.4.6 to magento/product-enterprise-edition version 2.4.6
Any one can you please provide the road map for this.
Thank You :)

Please check data migration tool https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-operations/tools/data-migration/basics/install
